# How to find the number of possible solutions of LP problems?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

Let us assume that we have a linear optimization problem (LP) that has multiple optimal solutions.

I would like to know if there is a solver or an algorithm that can provide the number of optimal solutions. I would also like to know if there has been any research on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are already results on this question. There are two cases to consider:

**If variables $\in \mathbb{R}+ $**:
Since the problem is linear, the constraints form a polygon, and if there is more than one solution, than it means that there is an infinite amount of them, all lie on an edge of the polygon. In this case it is clear that it is impossible to output all of them.

**If variables $\in \mathbb{N} $**: In this case, you can sequentially generate all solutions by adding new constraints. See for example [this paper](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2013/10/4103.pdf) or [this one](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.5329&rep=rep1&type=pdf)…or [this one](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-72792-7_22).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The integer case is more interesting to look at but why should the variables be positive in the continuous case?

Comment: No, they don't really have to be positive, its just that in practice that's what you want (you can always make a change of variables to have positive ones), It is necessary for the simplex. But no, it is not necessary.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

In the LP case (opposed to MIP) you most likely want to enumerate corner points or basic solutions. There is a low level pivoting algorithm described in Ralph E. Steuer, *Multiple Criteria Optimization: Theory, Computation, and Application*, Wiley, 1986.

The paper Sangbum Lee, Chan Phalakornkule, Michael M. Domach, Ignacio E Grossmann, *Recursive MILP model for finding all the alternate optima in LP models for metabolic networks*, Computers & Chemical Engineering, Volume 24, Issues 2–7, 15 July 2000, Pages 711-716 is also interesting. It enumerates all optimal bases using a MIP formulation. See also here for a [GAMS implementation](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions.html). This method can be optimized somewhat using the Cplex solution pool technology, see [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions-using.html).

Comment: Yeah, just LP case! The method that you present in your blog as well as the one in the paper are to enumerate all the solutions which is very practical. Yet I would like to get only the NUMBER of those solutions. But thanks for your answer and btw nice blog :)

Comment: I would not know how to get the number of optimal bases by not enumerating them.

Comment: I know it's hard (not impossible) but what if this number is huge

Comment: You just stop say at N=10k optimal bases. I just checked with a small problem and I can generate 10k solutions in about 25 seconds using Cplex's solution pool.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I should give it a try then!

Comment: The thing is that I have Enumerative combinatorics real world problem that I want to solve! I was not confident to model it as an ILP since it becomes intractable but with your remark, I will give it a try anyway, thanks :)