# Set up an integer programming problem so that all variables in the solution are different

Tags: linear-programming, matlab, integer-programming

I have a relatively simple minimisation problem. I have to minimise a linear function with many variables (more than 20), and I would like all the solutions to be different and in set $ x \in \{1,...,n \}$, where $n$ is the number of variables.

How to set up such a constraint for an integer programming solver?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's primarily about the usage of Matlab software, rather than the mathematics involved in the question.

Comment: I think this is not about Matlab per se, but about MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) in general.

Comment: Are your variable real or integer?

Comment: It says $x \in \{1,...,n\}$

Comment: This question has been addressed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1611196/how-to-find-the-number-of-possible-solutions-of-lp-problems/1611221#1611221

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because it's about mathematics and not about the usage of Matlab software. (cc @T.Bongers)

Comment: @Sally Seems reasonable, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

I read this question as: the vector $x$ should have elements $x_i \in \{1,...,n\}$ and they all should be different. I.e. $x_i \neq x_j$ if $i \neq j$.

One way of modeling this is with $n^2$ binary variables:
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_i b_{i,j} = 1\> \forall j \\
&\sum_j b_{i,j} = 1\> \forall i \\
&x_i = \sum_j j \cdot b_{i,j} \\
&b_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}$$
Think of $b$ as a permutation matrix.

Constraint programming solvers have typically a built-in **all-different** constraint, so they may be more suitable than a MIP solver.

If you mean: I repeatedly solve the model and each time I want a different solution, then you can add some integer cuts to forbid a previously found solution. Those integer cuts are somewhat complicated, but this post has an answer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/51948/43116.

Comment: do you have a reference for this strategy?

Comment: I would guess it is discussed in: Williams, H. Paul and Yan, Hong (2001) Representations of the 'all_different' predicate of constraint satisfaction in integer programming Informs Journal of Computing, 13 (2). 96-103.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I find the article very interesting, but I am not sure you can use it here. In the article, it deals with problems without objective functions, and generates different solutions to a constraint satisfaction problem. I might have to read it more carefully, but I am not sure you can use this strategy for minimization problems.

Comment: Because with an objective, IP algorithms will select variables to obtain one unique solution. Indeed, in your answer, you do not worry about the objective, but the problem is a minimization problem, which is why I do not think this approach can work here.

Comment: @Erwin : could it be also a nice case where programming ourself the branch and cut algorithm would be more efficient than using a solver ?

Comment: @user1952009 I don't know the answer to that. Sorry.

Comment: @Kuifje any algebraic constraint can be part of an optimization problem.